# Wrong TimeZoneOffset for Spain with reverse geocoding Here API

Tags: here-api

I use Here API for Reverse Geocoding. I get TimeZoneOffset from reverse geocoding API.

Few weeks ago I get a problem with same locations in Spain. Now Spain has UTC+2 time zone offset, but for same locations I get from Here API UTC+1 (not for all location). Those locations are always in Spain Peninsular.

This is an example with that problem:

[https://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?app_id={app_id}&app_code={app_code}&mode=retrieveAreas&prox=36.24639,-6.02333&language=es&locationattributes=adminInfo,timeZone](https://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?app_id=%7Bapp_id%7D&app_code=%7Bapp_code%7D&mode=retrieveAreas&prox=36.24639,-6.02333&language=es&locationattributes=adminInfo,timeZone)

Answer (score 0):

The TimeZoneOffset value is in UTC. Spain has 2 time zones in UTC+1 and UTC+2

Offset  Time Zone Abbreviation & Name   Example City
UTC +1  WEST    Western European Summer Time    Las Palmas
UTC +2  CEST    Central European Summer Time    Madrid

Comment: The problem with my example is the coordinates 36.24639,-6.02333 (Vejer de la Frontera, Cádiz, Spain) must be now in Central European Summer Time Madrid (UTC +2) but I get (UTC +1)

Comment: Hi, could you review bad assigned time zone for same Peninsular Spain places? Now Peninsular Spain is in UTC+2, like Balears Islands. Only Canary Islands are in UTC+1.